# Robocopy /xo Then copy newest files to an empty folder

Tags: robocopy

I want to use robocopy /xo to isolate only newly modified files.  After they are copied to the destination folder, I want to copy the files that were just copied to an empty folder.

I have already set up robocopy with maxage to try to catch files changed since yesterday (this repeats on the half hour) but I end up re-copying the same files even if they haven't changed.  This is why I moved to the /xo switch.  I understand the destination folder will have to have all the contents of the original directory in order to compare.  However, I want whatever files are  new to also be copied to a blank folder.

Comment: For example, if I have File 1, File 2, and File 3 in the original folder, and File 1 is modified an hour ago, my destination (call it destination 1) folder will get updated with the newer version of File 1 (It will have FIle 1, File 2, and File 3).  Next, I want File 1 only to be copied to an empty folder (destination folder #2) because I've identified that it's the only one to have been updated.  I still want to maintain the original destination folder to make sure my local machine is up-to-date.  The last copy to empty folder is an additional step.

Answer (score 0):

Run robocopy with the following options.

"maxage:1" makes robocopy to copy only files that are modified in the last 1 day.

"mir" is to mirror.

With "s" option, robocopy does not create directories which don't include any files modified in the last 1 days.

```
robocopy c:\source c:\destination /maxage:1 /mir /s
```

Comment: I'm copying from a folder that can change at any point during the day.  It's important I only pick up changed files, or else I will keep copying the same files that were modified in the last 24 hours (maxage).

I can use robocopy /xo to do just that.  What I want to do is copy any files that were just updated in the destination folder, and copy them to an empty folder.